# Oracle AQ - Write Custom Message that contains Char

Tags: java, oracle, jms

I have a field of the type CHAR and want to push a message to a queue in form of a java object. I know how to map varchar (by strings) but I don't know how to map a CHAR from the Oracle DB to java.

In detail: I create a POJO *Event* that implements `SQLData` and hence contains the methods `readSQL(SQLInput stream, String sqlType)` and `writeSQL(SQLOutput stream)`. But neither `SQLOutput` nor `SQLInput` offers a write/read method to write/read chars. How do I do that?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

CHAR also maps to String, but padded with spaces. If you have a solution for VARCHAR you can use it for CHAR as well, it is the same mapping. It may be a good idea to trim the padding spaces, depending on your application.